# 18.04 x11vnc failed to start and password problems

Tags: 18.04, vnc

18.04 Ubuntu and 9.13 x11vnc installed. I'm trying to set up my PC so I can VNC into my current session and have x11vnc run at startup. If I don't set a password I can vnc into my PC's current session fine on port 5900. When I set a password I cannot connect in. I can however connect into a new session on port 5901 which is not what I want.

On top of that, when I try create a service file to run at startup, I get a failed to start x11vnc message.

I'm using this blog: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12220 as my guide.

Below is the output I get when I try to start the service:

```
user@ubuntu-pc:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
user@ubuntu-pc:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
user@ubuntu-pc:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl start x11vnc.service
user@ubuntu-pc:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status x11vnc.service
● x11vnc.service - "x11vnc"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-10-05 10:22:06 EDT; 1s ago
 Process: 7446 ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth guess -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass (code=exited,     status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 7446 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 05 10:22:06 ubuntu-pc systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 05 10:22:06 ubuntu-pc systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 05 10:22:06 ubuntu-pc systemd[1]: Stopped "x11vnc".
Oct 05 10:22:06 ubuntu-pc systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 05 10:22:06 ubuntu-pc systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 05 10:22:06 ubuntu-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start "x11vnc".
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1** When I attempt to VNC in I get "connection attempt refused" then I run *x11vnc* and VNC in at port 5900 with no password, then I can see my current screen. After running *x11vnc -storepasswd  /home/ then x11vnc -rfbauth /home/hudsona/.vnc/passwd* I can VNC into my current session with a password.

This question helped me out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405185/password-problem-x11vnc

**Edit 2** After creating that .desktop file from the question I linked in Edit 1, I can reboot, log in then VNC from another machine on port 5900 and get in. Without logging in I can VNC in from another machine on port 5901 but on my VNC viewer all I get is a grey checkered screen with an "X" mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

After more research this question lead me to the fix for the grey screen issue: [VNC grey screen with Xubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924139/vnc-grey-screen-with-xubuntu-17-04)

Between this and the .desktop file create from **Edit 2** my questions have been answered.