# why ubuntu desktop showing nothing when vnc?

Tags: 18.04, vnc, window-manager, window-management

I was able to ssh to my ubuntu and started vnc server, then vnc to it form my mac but this is what I found see the screenshot. I do not see any desktop , when I mouse over a cross sign cursor appears instead of a normal mouse pointer.

[image]

Comment: Related: [VNC grey screen with Xubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924139/vnc-grey-screen-with-xubuntu-17-04)